# Play framework make http request from play server to "somesite.com" and send the response back to the browser

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.10, playframework-2.2

I'm developing an application using Play framework in scala. I have to handle the below use case in my application.

For a particular request from the browser to the play server the Play server should make an http request to some external server (for Eg: somesite.com) and send the response from this request back to the web browser.

I have written the below code to send the request to external serever in the controller.

```
val holder = WS.url("http://somesite.com")
val futureResponse = holder.get
```

Now how do I send back the response recieved from "somesite.com" back to the browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an example in the [Play documentation for **WS**](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS), under **Using in a controller**; I've adapted it to your scenario:

```
def showSomeSiteContent = Action.async {
  WS.url("http://somesite.com").get().map { response =>
    Ok(response.body)
  }
}
```

The key thing to note is the idiomatic use of `map()` on the `Future` that you get back from the `get` call - code inside this `map` block will be executed once the `Future` has completed successfully.

The `Action.async` "wrapper" tells the Play framework that you'll be returning a `Future[Response]` and that you want *it* to do the necessary waiting for things to happen, as explained in the [**Handling Asynchronous Results** documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAsync).

Answer (score 3):

You may also be interested in dynamically returning the status and content type:

```
def showSomeSiteContent = Action.async {
  WS.url("http://somesite.com").get().map { response =>
    Status(response.status)(response.body).as(response.ahcResponse.getContentType)
  }
}
```

- Dynamic status could help if the URL/service you call fails to answer correctly.
- Dynamic content type can be handy if your URL/service can return different content HTML/XML... depending on some dynamic parameter.